# why javascript can not access property?

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype

I am using `typescript` decorators like this:

```
function logParameter(target: any, key : string, index : number) {
  var metadataKey = `__log_${key}_parameters`;
  console.log(target);
  console.log(metadataKey === "__log_move_parameters");
  console.log(target[metadataKey]); // always undefined
}


class Horse{
    public __log_move_parameters: number[];

    move(@logParameter distanceInMeters = 45) {
        console.log("Galloping...");
    }
}
Horse.prototype.__log_move_parameters = [];
let tom: Horse = new Horse();

tom.move(34);
```

I find out that `target[metadataKey]` is always `undefined`, but when I log out `target` I do have `__log_move_parameters` in `target`

Here is the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20logParameter(target%3A%20any%2C%20key%20%3A%20string%2C%20index%20%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20var%20metadataKey%20%3D%20%60__log_%24%7Bkey%7D_parameters%60%3B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(target)%3B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(metadataKey%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22__log_move_parameters%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(target%5BmetadataKey%5D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20if%20(Array.isArray(target%5BmetadataKey%5D))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20target%5BmetadataKey%5D.push(index)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20target%5BmetadataKey%5D%20%3D%20%5Bindex%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Horse%7B%0D%0A%09public%20__log_move_parameters%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%20%20%20%20move(%40logParameter%20distanceInMeters%20%3D%2045)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Galloping...%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AHorse.prototype.__log_move_parameters%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Alet%20tom%3A%20Horse%20%3D%20new%20Horse()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atom.move(34)%3B)

Comment: `__ugly__habits__from__other__languages__`

Answer (score 0):

`target` doesn't get the property until after that code runs. You're being tricked (as so many of us have been, so many times) by the fact that when you log an object to the console, the console has a **live** reference to the object; when you click the expand arrow next to the object in the console, it shows you the state of the object **as of when you expanded it**, not as of when it was logged.

[Here's an updated version](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20logParameter(target%3A%20any%2C%20key%20%3A%20string%2C%20index%20%3A%20number)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20var%20metadataKey%20%3D%20%60__log_%24%7Bkey%7D_parameters%60%3B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(target)%3B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(metadataKey%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22__log_move_parameters%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(target%5BmetadataKey%5D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20if%20(Array.isArray(target%5BmetadataKey%5D))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20target%5BmetadataKey%5D.push(index)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20else%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20target%5BmetadataKey%5D%20%3D%20%5Bindex%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Horse%7B%0D%0A%09public%20__log_move_parameters%3A%20number%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%20%20%20%20move(%40logParameter%20distanceInMeters%20%3D%2045)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Galloping...%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AHorse.prototype.__log_move_parameters%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Alet%20tom%3A%20Horse%20%3D%20new%20Horse()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atom.move(34)%3B) with these two lines added:

```
console.log("target", JSON.stringify(target));
console.log("in?", "__log_move_parameters" in target);
```

They show

```
target {}
in? false
```